# How to order a dataframe using the order of the another to make matches between lines in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I want to check if there are changes between rows, but the people are in different order and I want to have it in the same exact order.

This is an example of the data in the original database:

```
structure(list(PCD = c(10101L, 10101L, 10101L, 10101L, 10101L, 
30201L, 30201L, 30201L, 30201L, 30201L, 30201L, 30108L, 30108L, 
30108L, 30108L), AE = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), UGM = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Household = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Home = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Line = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Name = c("Fabiola Nevado", 
"Kevin Molina", "Ana Montado", "Julia Mendoza", "Luis Ulate", 
"Julian Ugalde", "Hannia Lopez", "John Smith", "Jazmin Rivera", 
"Francis Gonzales", "Sharon Martinez", "Adriana Lopez", "Esteban Bonilla", 
"Aubrey Smith", "Kate Fernandez"), Sex = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

[image]

Here is an example of the dataframe adjusted:

```
structure(list(PCD = c(10101L, 10101L, 10101L, 10101L, 10101L, 
30201L, 30201L, 30201L, 30201L, 30201L, 30201L, 30108L, 30108L, 
30108L, 30108L), AE = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), UGM = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Household = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Home = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Line = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Name = c("Julia Mendoza", 
"Kevin Molina", "Ana Montado", "Fabiola Nevado", "Luis Ulate", 
"John Smith", "Hannia Lopez", "Julian Ugalde", "Jazmin Rivera", 
"Francis Gonzales", "Sharon Martinez", "Adriana Lopez", "Esteban Bonilla", 
"Aubrey Smith", "Kate Fernandez"), Sex = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

[image]

How can I sort the last dataframe to make it has the order of the first dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

`arrange` by all but `PCD`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(across(-PCD))

    PCD AE UGM Household Home Line             Name Sex
1  10101  1   1        20    1    1   Fabiola Nevado   1
2  10101  1   1        20    1    2     Kevin Molina   2
3  10101  1   1        20    1    3      Ana Montado   1
4  10101  1   1        20    1    4    Julia Mendoza   1
5  10101  1   1        20    1    5       Luis Ulate   2
6  30201  2   1        50    1    1    Julian Ugalde   2
7  30201  2   1        50    1    2     Hannia Lopez   1
8  30201  2   1        50    1    3       John Smith   2
9  30201  2   1        50    1    4    Jazmin Rivera   1
10 30201  2   1        50    1    5 Francis Gonzales   2
11 30201  2   1        50    1    6  Sharon Martinez   1
12 30108  5   2         2    1    1    Adriana Lopez   1
13 30108  5   2         2    1    2  Esteban Bonilla   2
14 30108  5   2         2    1    3     Aubrey Smith   1
15 30108  5   2         2    1    4   Kate Fernandez   1
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to have all the information, including the sex from the first dataframe with the other

Comment: Frankly it's quite unclear to me what you want to do. Sounds like you would need to join the data by Name in order to gather variables from both datasets corresponding to a given Name?

Comment: What I want to do is to sort the people by name to have in a single data frame the original one with the variables of the same person in the second base to see if there are changes into the variables

Answer (score 0):

Using `match()` you could order your people in the second data (`df2`) with the same order in the first data (`df1`). To do this you need to provide to match the matching vector. Here the matching vector is the `Name` in `df1` which take it to order the names in `df2` accordingly. Then you can check both `df1` and `df2` using `identical()` to check the order of name which should get `TRUE` if they are identical:

```
# order names in df2 based on those in df1:
df2<-df2[match(df2$Name, df1$Name),]

#check if they are in the same order:
identical(df1$Name,df2$Name)
TRUE
```

Comment: What can I if the names has different letters?

Comment: In this case, if possible I would match by `sub-strings` if they could match between two `dfs`. But this is another topic and would ask as another question.